# Kettle transformation from Text Input to HBase output - Mapping issue

Tags: hbase, kettle

I am trying to evaluate the Kettle integration with HBase and to start with, i tried the example at http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/BAD/Loading+Data+into+HBase with my changes in the load_hbase.ktr.

I use ubuntu 12.04 LTS, Kettle 4.3.0, HBase 0.96.0.

As i have issues in opening spoon on my ubuntu box, i create the job and transformations using spoon from windows.
But for the sake of example, i dont even do that as i use the already provided file.

I use pan.sh to run the transformation and i am getting the following exception
Problem getting mapping inforation: Mapping "weblogs,pageviews" does not exist!

From the other posts on the forum, i understand that the mapping needs to be created in Hbase manually.

My understanding is that when spoon is used to create the transformation, it automatically creates the mapping on HBase based on the values provided on the UI.
Can you please let me know how to create pentaho mapping in HBase without Spoon or any other UI (UI does not work on my Ubuntu box)?

Answer (score 0):

The HBase dialog in Kettle is used to manually create the mappings.  The recommended way to do so would be to connect from Kettle and use the UI.

Ubuntu 12.04 is a supported operating system and Kettle should run on it.  If you're having problems, please ensure you've installed libwebkitgtk-1.0-0

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
```